# I’ve officially counted to infinity!

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, story, situation

> Sarah called me today and explained that she had counted to infinity. I shrugged and said it was impossible. She said that since I didn’t believe her, she would do it again, and this time in only ten minutes. I thought it was impossible but she did it right before my eyes!

How did Sarah count to infinity in only ten minutes?

### Hints

Sarah started slow, but as time went on she got incredibly fast!

### Clarifications

Sarah indeed counted all the way to infinity. She provided mathematical proof that she could count any infinite set, to include $א‎_0$, in any finite time span.

Comment: Welcome back! :)

Comment: Oh, and just so there is no confusion here, does Sarah mean that she counts *to* infinity as opposed to counting *towards* infinity? There is a difference, and I feel like this is an important, but subtle, detail to address.

Comment: @MrPie All the way to infinity!

Comment: This question feels a bit too broad. Are you sure there's one demonstrably correct answer to this one?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 I’m pretty sure there is one way to count to the end of an infinite set in a finite time span.

Comment: An appropriate question for your username, @PerpetualJ.

Comment: My concern is that there may be more than one valid answer, and without specifying further restrictions, the “correct” one becomes an arbitrary choice. There’s already many good answers that could potentially be correct, which feeds into my concern

Comment: @PiIsNot3 the correct answer will have a mathematical explanation as to how Sarah is able to count to the end of an infinite set in a finite time span.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Several different answers already do so. As it stands, this seems to be too broad.

Comment: Has Sarah studied the one-point compactification of the real line?

Comment: @CarlChristian No, but she did prove the continuum hypothesis! :)

Comment: This question will appear under HNQ, I know it ;)

Comment: @MrPie It was the hottest question until closure automatically removed it.

Comment: @noedne 18 hours in: 5k views, 17 answers, 12 upvotes, 13 downvotes, 23 upvotes on the accepted answer, Jesus Christ!

Comment: @MrPie what’s even crazier is the sheer amount of negative feedback on my puzzle! Didn’t expect people to downvote on a puzzle related to supertasks so much. I think this is my only puzzle with a negative score lol

Comment: 'Tis unfortunately because of [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) recent Meta post, which I happen to agree with, but to a partial extent. At first I didn't but after looking at this puzzle of yours, I have changed my mind; it's too much fun, @PerpetualJ!

Comment: @MrPie Well, I wouldn’t say this is open ended, I try to avoid those; but it was broad in the sense that I could have refined it to make it more clear and concise. Hindsight is 20/20 though, I’ll make a better one soon lol

Comment: @PerpetualJ it is difficult making a nice puzzle here on PSE. One must have that fine balance between too much (which would quickly give the answer away) and too less (which would open cans of many answers). I believe that mastering this fine balance only comes with experience ;)

Comment: Added after closure: The one point compactification provides a bijection between the extended real line and the unit circle. Simply draw a unit circle with origo at (0,1). For each point x on the real line draw a straight line to the point (0,2). It will intersect the circle at one point p = p(x). This is a bijection between the real line and the circle save the point (0,2). You will find that infinity is mapped to this special point. Starting at (0,0) and moving along the edge of the circle, say 18 degrees pr. minute, Sarah can count to infinity in 10 minutes without violating physics.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This feels underspecified:

> clearly Sarah is *not* counting 1, 2, 3, ... (infinitely many numbers go here), infinity; so she's doing *something* else; but there are quite a lot of something-elses that she could do, and all of them are kinda cheaty, and the question here is what *specific* kinda-cheaty thing she did.

Here are a few possibilities. One:

> She wrote numbers down *on their sides*, starting at 1 and proceeding as far as 8. An 8 on its side looks very much like the usual mathematical symbol for infinity.

Two:

> She started from, let's say, "infinity minus 100" and counted up. (There are in fact [number systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) in which something a bit like "infinity minus 100" is an actual number.)

Three:

> She counted *down* from, let's say, "infinity plus 100". (You can do something like that in the surreal numbers, mentioned above, but also in other simpler systems such as the [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).)

Four:

> She started counting normally, and at some point went "... and so on; infinity." I personally wouldn't (ahahaha) count that as *counting* to infinity, but then I don't think I'd count anything as counting to infinity other than the thing she obviously didn't do.

Five:

> Sarah is able to count *arbitrarily fast* (maybe she's an archangel or something, not a human) and she said each number twice as quickly as its predecessor; after twice the time it took her to say "one", she had named all the positive integers and then said "infinity".

Apparently that last one is what the OP had in mind. Here are some more details.

> Suppose it takes her two seconds to say "one", and then each new number is said 0.5% faster than the previous one -- so the next number takes 1.99 seconds, the next just over 1.98 seconds, etc. Then counting *all* the positive integers takes $2\left(1+\frac{199}{200}+\left(\frac{199}{200}\right)^2+\left(\frac{199}{200}\right)^3+\cdots\right)$ seconds, which equals $\frac2{1-\frac{199}{200}}$ or 400 seconds. This gives Sarah plenty of time to take a big breath and add "infinity", all within ten minutes.

Comment: I think you're missing an option: she counted to five -- she counted "All" "the" "way" "to" "infinity" as five words, which is a valid interpretation of what she said

Comment: @postmortes must be a very slow counter then if it takes her ten minutes ;)

Comment: @Mark I agree :)

Comment: Gareth, your last one is the closest explanation! We all know there is no final number, but you can count an infinite set in a finite time span for sure!

Comment: I forgot to include, if you just edit your answer to show the supporting math and how she counted an infinite set in finite time you’ll have it!

Comment: OK, done. I decided to make her speed up more slowly. 10 minutes is plenty of time :-).

Comment: My issue with this approach is that it is not physically feasible but I think you can make it so by drawing a parallel with something we know (or surmise, at least) to be a continuum. I've tried to address this in the answer below but there may be a better approach.

Comment: @hexomino You should look at the theory of supertasks.

Answer (score 28):

I find it hard to believe she managed this in only 10 minutes, but all she needs to do is count to 1,461,559,270,678...

> she just needs to do it in base 36, in which case the digits of the number are `INFINITY`.

Comment: She could count 200+ billion digits less if she used base 35

Comment: Arguably this is the only answer yet that _actually_ describes a finite process that could in any way be described _correctly_ as "counting to infinity". (_Arguably_.)

Comment: maybe she rot13(pbhagrq ol 7OW2OG (442628489 onfr gra) yrnivat bayl 3302 vgrengvbaf, rnfvyl qbar va 10 zvahgrf!).  on a side note, who knew rot13(gur cevzr snpgbef bs VASVAVGL jrer (onfr 10) 2, 13, 127, 149, 18923, naq 2970661?)

Answer (score 26):

> There goes one Infiniti G35! And there goes another!
>
>  [image: Infiniti G35]
>
>  There. I've counted two Infiniti. ;)

Comment: Hahaha this was awesome lol

Comment: Ah, the punch buggy no punch back answer :)

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps

> clever Sarah went the appropriate "I" page in the dictionary and counted word entries until she reached "infinity"

Comment: If so, she didn't count to infinity, she (at best) counted to "infinity". (Personally I don't think even _that_ is a correct description of what she did.) But I don't expect whatever answer OP has in mind to be much more convincing than this.

Comment: I don't see how this fits with the "Sarah started slow, but as time went on she got incredibly fast!" hint.

Comment: It was posted before that hint was added. (As were almost all the answers, including one of mine that already does the slow-then-faster thing. I suppose the hint was added more to make the question less too-broad than because it was needed as a hint :-).)

Comment: But that's only to "infinity" - far too low.  If you instead listed Disney catch-phrases, then you could count "To Infinity, and Beyond"

Answer (score 17):

Did Sarah count

> All of the avengers movies up to and including infinity war?

Answer (score 12):

> She counted "to infinity", 10 letters, 1 space.

Comment: Ah, that explains the timing as well, unlike some of the other answers! (+1) Good first post! :P

Comment: That explains ten minutes?

Answer (score 10):

How about counting:

> $\frac{1}{1000}, \frac{1}{999}, \frac{1}{998}, \cdots, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{0}$

Comment: Your final term is not defined... but.... meh ;)

Answer (score 9):

I can do it in 15 minutes. Duh.

> [image]

Comment: Do you actually mean 40 minutes?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier 15 minutes because he rotated it 90 degrees (desperately trying not to spoil)

Comment: @Steve-O Thanks, I see it now.

Answer (score 7):

Possible mathematical answer

I think this is linked to

> [Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)

Possible approach

> Sarah defines for you a new number system. The number $1$ is represent by saying the letter "a" for a duration of $10$ seconds, the number $2$ is represented by saying the letter "a" for $5$ seconds, the number $3$ is represented by saying the letter "a" for a duration of $2.5$ seconds and, in general, the number $n$ is represented by saying the letter "a" for a duration of $\frac{10}{2^{n-1}}$ seconds. 
>  She then says "a" for a duration of $20$ seconds to count to infinity.

Comment: There’s a name for this phenomenon!

Comment: @PerpetualJ I've added an extra line. Is this the phenomenon you're talking about?

Comment: Surely that is counting to 0, not to ∞?  (since `n = 1+ln(10/t)/ln(2)`)

Comment: The 20 seconds, is counting 1,2,3,4,5,... consecutively. I understand there is ambiguity here (1 is the same as 2 2s etc) but I decided it was not important to address in the context of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The definition of infinity in some circles is

> the highest conceivable number.

Therefore, all Sarah needs to do is count to

> the highest number she knows of, be that a hundred, a thousand, whatever. Because she cannot think of any number higher than that, that is her "infinity".

Comment: Finitism much (it seems that Sarah is accepting the highest number she can count to as infinity)?

Answer (score 4):

Sarah isn't great at counting but she is great at improving anything she does while she is doing it.

> Therefore, every time she counts a number she can count it faster than the previous one.  The improvement it's not that spectacular, and to count one number still takes her 99.8% of the time it took to count the previous one.
>
> This way, if counting to 1 took Sarah 1 second, the time it will take Sarah to count to n is: $1+1\cdot 0.998 + 1\cdot 0.998^2 + .... + 1\cdot 0.998^n$
> Since that's just a geometric series, it's sum to infinite is $\frac{1}{1-0.998}=500$ seconds.
>
> That is, just thanks to keeping improving continuously, Sarah can count to infinite in 8 minutes and 20 seconds.

Comment: I like this one! I actually didn’t expect another answer to come in with good mathematical arguments! +1

Answer (score 4):

Sarah is also known as

> **Chuck Norris**

Indeed:

> *"[Chuck Norris counted to infinity. Twice.](https://chucknorrisfacts.net/facts?page=21#loading_522)"*

And since

> *"[Chuck Norris has his own Gender.](https://chucknorrisfacts.net/facts?page=35#loading_972)"*, Sarah is a suitable second name for them.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> She starts counting and for each number she takes half the time to count to the next number, through this method you can count to infinity in a finite time.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the right approach (even if it is not the correct answer)?

> Time is finite, yes, but continuous, so it contains an infinite number of individual positions. If we apply, for example, the function f: x -> 1/(10-x) to the interval of minutes [0,10] belonging to the Real Numbers, just before the 10 minutes we will have reached infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the puzzle being already solved, I have another take on this.

All she needs to do is

> use a diverging function.

For instance, she could say

> -log(3), -log(2), -log(1), -log(0)

Which is in agreement with the hint that she goes incredibly fast in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Did Sarah perhaps say once:

> $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x = \infty$

Comment: Sarah would have to say this very slowly to reach ten minutes, which would be impractical if @PerpetualJ was paying for every minute during the phone call!

Answer (score -2):

My answer is:

> As Sarah got really fast, time stopped...according to Einstein's relativity..hence she did it....I know this sounds absurd but ...meh!